# align not properly aligning for multiple equations for multiple points

Tags: align, amsmath

I've been wanting to get something like this :

[image: Example 1]

But with another align point under the f_0 arrow kinda like the following
[image: Example 2]

No need for me to be as clean as the second example, I just want the arrows aligned. However the code:

```
\begin{align*}
0 \xleftarrow{f_{2}} Hom_{R}(R^{\oplus 2},R) \cong R^{\oplus 2} &\xleftarrow{f_{1}} Hom_{R}(R^{\oplus 3},R) \cong R^{\oplus 3} &\xleftarrow{f_{0}} Hom_{R}(R,R) \cong R \xleftarrow{g} 0 \\
&{} (x,y,x+y) &\leftarrow 1 \\
(1,y) &\leftarrow (1,0,0) \\
(1,-x) &\leftarrow (0,1,0) \\
(-1,0) &\leftarrow (0,0,1) \\
\end{align*}
```

Has been aligning it with the g arrow like this:
[image: Example 3]

I would also want the (x,y,x+y) <- 1 to be in one block like in the other ones.
EDIT: since I wasn’t clear the first time, I want the arrow that takes 1 to (x,y,x+y) to be aligned with the f_0 arrow not the g one.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desired result remains me to commutative diagram, however unfortunately it is not clear to me, where are positioned elements of the second row. So far I guessing, that you like to have something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14159mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2em,
                   row sep=0ex]
0   &   \ar[l,"f_{2} " ']  (R^{\oplus 2},R) \cong R^{\oplus 2} 
        &   \ar[l,"f_{1}" ']  \mathrm{Hom}_{R}(R^{\oplus 3},R) \cong R^{\oplus 3} 
                &   \ar[l,"f_{0}" '] \mathrm{Hom}_{R}(R,R) \cong R
                    &   \ar[l, "g" '] 0    \\
    &   &   (x,y,x+y) 
            &   &   \ar[ll] 1       \\
    &   (1,y) 
        &   \ar[l]  (1,0,0)
                &   &               \\
    &   (1,-x) 
        &   \ar[l]  (0,1,0) 
                &   &               \\ 
    &   (-1,0) 
        &   \ar[l]  (0,0,1) 
                &   &               \\ 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

*Addendum*: or it may be like the following:

[image]

as follows from discussion with @Bernard (thank you very much!):

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14159mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2em,
                   row sep=0ex]
0   &   \ar[l,"f_{2} " ']  (R^{\oplus 2},R) \cong R^{\oplus 2}
        &   \ar[l,"f_{1}" ']  \mathrm{Hom}_{R}(R^{\oplus 3},R) \cong R^{\oplus 3}
                &   \ar[l,"f_{0}" '] \mathrm{Hom}_{R}(R,R) \cong R
                    &   \ar[l, "g" '] 0 \\
    &   &   (x,y,x+y)
            &   \ar[l] 1
                    &                   \\
    &   (1,y)
        &   \ar[l]  (1,0,0)
                &   &                   \\
    &   (1,-x)
        &   \ar[l]  (0,1,0)
                &   &                   \\
    &   (-1,0)
        &   \ar[l]  (0,0,1)
                &   &                   \\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The rightmost `1` shouldn't be under the `0`, methinks.

Comment: @Bernard, under penultimate node?  It may be, but about this the question is a bit unclear to me ... however it is simple to move `1` for one place to the left.

Comment: I agree the question is somewhat unclear, but mapping 1 from the zero module to whatever looks like nonsense (albeit I love nonsense humour ;o))

Comment: @Bernard - Excellent use of the word 'methinks', je pense. :-)

Comment: @Mico: Great minds think together… :o)

Comment: Thanks a lot the addendum is exactly what I was looking for and again sorry for not making it clear the first time

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (obtained by removing one instance each of `&` from lines 1 and 2 of your code)?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom} % optional
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
0 \xleftarrow{f_{2}} \Hom_{R}(R^{\oplus2},R) \cong R^{\oplus2} 
 &\xleftarrow{f_{1}} \Hom_{R}(R^{\oplus3},R) \cong R^{\oplus3} 
  \xleftarrow{f_{0}} \Hom_{R}(R,R) \cong R \xleftarrow{g} 0 \\
(x,y,x+y) &\gets 1 \\
    (1,y) &\gets (1,0,0) \\
   (1,-x) &\gets (0,1,0) \\
   (-1,0) &\gets (0,0,1) \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you prefer, you could replace the instances of the left-pointing `\gets` arrow (aka `\leftarrow`) with a version that has a "base" at its start, i.e., the opposite of the `\mapsto` arrow. Let's call the macro that does the opposite of `\mapsto`, well, `\mapsfrom`. Several math font symbol packages, including the `\newtxmath` and `\newpxmath` packages, and most OpenType-based math fonts (for use under LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package) actually define `\mapsfrom` in just this way. Unfortunately, `\mapsfrom` is not defined in the `amssymb` font package. If your document happens to use Computer Modern or Latin Modern fonts, you can still create a `\mapsfrom` macro as follows: (a) load the `graphicx` package (for its `\raisebox` and `\rotatebox` macros) and (b) issue the following instruction in the preamble:

```
\providecommand\mapsfrom{%
    \mathrel{\raisebox{0.31ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\mapsto$}}}}
```

Comment: Simple and nice ... (+1)!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an array:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\newcommand{\xmapsfrom}[2][]{\xleftarrow[#1]{#2}\mapsfromchar}


\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\ff}{\hphantom{f_0}}
\begin{array}{@{} c >{{}}c<{{}} c >{{}}c<{{}} c @{}}
0 \xleftarrow{f_2} \Hom_R(R^{{\oplus}2},R) \cong R^{{\oplus}2} &
\xleftarrow{f_1} & \Hom_R(R^{{\oplus}3},R) \cong R^{{\oplus}3} &
\xleftarrow{f_0} & \Hom_R(R,R)\cong R \xleftarrow{g} 0
\\
&& \hspace*{\fill} (x,y,x+y) & \xmapsfrom{\ff} & 1 \hspace*{\fill}
\\
\hspace*{\fill} (1,y) & \xmapsfrom{\ff} & (1,0,0) \hspace*{\fill}
\\
\hspace*{\fill} (1,-x) & \xmapsfrom{\ff} & (0,1,0) \hspace*{\fill}
\\
\hspace*{\fill} (-1,0) & \xmapsfrom{\ff} & (0,0,1) \hspace*{\fill}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

The local command `\ff` is used for equalizing `\xmapsfrom` with `\xleftarrow`.
With `\hspace*{\fill}` I can change the alignment in the columns.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this one too !